# What is the value of MINT_SIZE, the constant from the Solana spl-token package?

Tags: spl-token, mint

When creating a spl-token mint, we pass in the number for supply. What is the value of MINT_SIZE?  Is there a way to create a spl-token mint with infinite supply? If not, What is the maximum number of the underlying unsigned datatype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MINT_SIZE` = 82, its the size (in bytes) of the account data for a Mint Account.

A standard Mint Account has the following layout:

```
pub struct Mint {
    /// Optional authority used to mint new tokens. The mint authority may only
    /// be provided during mint creation. If no mint authority is present
    /// then the mint has a fixed supply and no further tokens may be
    /// minted.
    pub mint_authority: COption<Pubkey>,
    /// Total supply of tokens.
    pub supply: u64,
    /// Number of base 10 digits to the right of the decimal place.
    pub decimals: u8,
    /// Is `true` if this structure has been initialized
    pub is_initialized: bool,
    /// Optional authority to freeze token accounts.
    pub freeze_authority: COption<Pubkey>,
}
```

The `supply` is `u64` type, so that would be the limit for the maximum supply.